# Domain been on clientHold, pendingDelete for 2 months, now is also redemptionPeriod

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, whois

I've been tracking a certain domain on whois for the past month now.

Expires on 2021-01-04

Updated on 2021-01-03

Status: clientHold, pendingDelete, redemptionPeriod

The redemptionPeriod status only got added yesterday. What does this all mean? I was under the impression that since it was pendingDelete, it was only a matter of time before the domain would be available again. But it's been in the status clientHold, pendingDelete since the start of January, and yesterday it has now added redemptionPeriod too..

Can someone explain to me what's going on? Will this domain ever be available again? Thank you

Comment: What tld is it?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/130954/how-can-a-domain-be-showing-as-pendingdelete-redemptionperiod-but-not-expire